# Combo Box (dropdown) skipped on tab but works on shift tab

Tags: .net, winforms, drop-down-menu, combobox, tabstop

In win forms i have a drop down; no matter what i do the tab order wont work for it. tabIndex is right and tabstop is set to true ; control always skips this dropdown but when doing shift tab it works.
All other controls are in tab order, any ideas?
[image]

Comment: That's a lot of containers. 61 and 46. Do you really have this structure of controls? if not, perhaps a reordering is really overdue

Comment: its in a tab control that why its showing these containers

Comment: I removed the text box next to drop down and added a new one, then tab ordering started working

Comment: Can only guess that the taborder was put off by the number of controls present. By the way, how many controls do you have on that form?

Comment: restart visual studio, reboot, if that all fails use Spy++ to see its handle - also is this in Design-Time or Run Time? - I ask because your screenshot is design time and I've had weird issues like this in Winforms when I did something strange cant remember exactly but it was like creating a combobox outside the InitializeComponent and wondered why wasn't visible at Design Time. I'll let you know if I have `more bigger` idea's.

Comment: /facepalm, there was code behind that skipping control explicitly. Sorry guys.